# Finding table cell using locator after tableCellAddress finds the cell

Tags: xpath, html-table, cell, selenium-rc

I have a JSP page populated by javascript resulting in a typical table element cascade `<table><tbody><tr><td>`.  After population I see the text I want using

```
 getTable("tableLister.listTable.1.1")
```

The table also has a `class=clsDisplayTableBody`.
I want to click the check box in column 0 for the row of interest.  However, all of these tests fail

```
 isElementPresent("//*[text()="+cellContents+"]/../td[0]"))
 isElementPresent("//table[@class='clsDisplayTableBody']//tr[1]/td[0]"))
 isElementPresent("css='clsDisplayTableBody' tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(0)"))
 isElementPresent("//xpath=id('tableLister.listTable')/descendant::tr[1]/descendant::td[0]"))
 isElementPresent("//table[@id='tableLister.listTable']//tbody/tr[1]/td[0]"))
 isElementPresent("//table[@id='tableLister.listTable']//tr[1]/td[0]"))
```

Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: You haven't provided any XML document, how do you think anyone can understand what these expressions are intended to select?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation of one of the problems with all XPath expressions.

Comment: I disagree. This question isn't well-defined. Downvote is mine.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to click the check box in
>   column 0 for the row of interest.
>   However, all of these tests fail

```
isElementPresent("//*[text()="+cellContents+"]/../td[0]"))  
isElementPresent("//table[@class='clsDisplayTableBody']//tr[1]/td[0]"))  
isElementPresent("css='clsDisplayTableBody' tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(0)"))  
isElementPresent("//xpath=id('tableLister.listTable')/descendant::tr[1]/descendant::td[0]")) 
isElementPresent("//table[@id='tableLister.listTable']//tbody/tr[1]/td[0]")) 
isElementPresent("//table[@id='tableLister.listTable']//tr[1]/td[0]"))
```

**One obvious error is using `0` as index. XPath is 1-based**.

You may be closer to obtaining the wanted result after you increase the indexes by 1.